# Add /Remove element(ckeditor) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I need some change on this code http://jsfiddle.net/Ddtnw/.

I'd like

- one delete button by line to delete the current line
- the id of the fieldset and the legend change (ex: if we delete the second block the id of the third change to second)
- instead of fieldsets I whant to do the same thing with CKEditor.

Could you help me for that ?

PS: Sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't change the rest of your code, but this fiddle does what you want, I guess:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ddtnw/5/

Comment: Yes but, the div that contains the fieldset remains, and it does not recount to change the names and id. I know I need to use while in the  suppression part, but I do not know how.